# problem to concatenate the index of a pandas series with a string

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have the index of row concanate to the a string in a dataframe column,
like C-00000001 where C- is the string and 01 is the index format with 9 characters...
i tried a lot of thing without solution...

```
df_complete['Code du client *']="C-"+ str(df_complete.index)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str(…)` will give you a unique string, that will be broadcasted to all rows.

You need to use a vectorial transformation with `astype`:

```
df_complete['Code du client *'] = 'C-' + df_complete.index.astype(str)
```

If you have a range index and want to ensure 9 characters, use `zfill`:

```
'C-' + df_complete.index.astype(str).str.zfill(9)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! i don't know what is vectorial transformation, i'll search about it!!